# when i run idegen.sh,show File system loop detected

Tags: android

When I execute ./development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh ,
show
find: File system loop detected; xxx is part of the same file system loop as `xxx is part of the same file system loop as xxx
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjMrj.png)